# sed command modifying a file while another sed command modifies it too

Tags: sed

My question revolves around a process I'm using to update a status file.  I have a process running which does a simple

```
sed -i "s/info/newinfo/" file.txt
```

But this process can be called multiple times.

My question is, if two processes are running a sed command to modify the file at the same time, would that cause a problem?

I tried to test this by running 2 at commands at the same time doing two different sed modifications.  They seem to work fine but I don't know if they were actually simultaneously or not.  Maybe the command is so fast that it won't have a problem with read and write access from two different processes.

Comment: Yes... This seem work, mostly on small files, but on big file this become quickly a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Ok let show, with a *not so big* file:

```
cd /tmp
seq 1000000 2000000  > mediumfile.txt
ls -hl mediumfile.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  7.7M Sep 26 16:53 host  file.txt
wc mediumfile.txt 
1000001 1000001 8000008 host  file.txt
```

Ok, there is 1000k lines in my 7.7Mb file.

If I drop 2 x 1001 lines simultaneously by **two separated (*stream*) process** (from 1801000 to 1802000 and from 1803000 to 1804000).

```
sed '/1803000/,/1804000/d' -i mediumfile.txt & \
    sed '/1801000/,/1802000/d' -i mediumfile.txt ;wait
[1] 30727
[1]+  Done                    sed '/1803000/,/1804000/d' -i mediumfile.txt

wc -l mediumfile.txt 
999000 host  file.txt
```

There are 1k line too much!

```
grep '180[13]400' mediumfile.txt
1803400
```

So it is.